# Include Newest Note and Comment in List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, controller

I have to include both the newest `Note` and `Comment` with view model that I am passing to my list view but I cannot figure out how to include it in the view model.

I tried to do include but after I type p it will not give me a list of my properties for `MinimumProductInfo` which `ProductNotes` is a property for it.

Here is the controller code I am trying:

```
public ActionResult MinimumProductInfoList()
{
     var Model = _minimumProductInfo.GetAll();

     var Notes = db.ProductNotes.Where(p => p.NoteTypeFlag == "p").OrderByDescending(p => p.NoteDate).First();
     var Comments = db.ProductNotes.Where(p => p.NoteTypeFlag == "c").OrderByDescending(p => p.NoteDate).First();

     var Model = db.MinimumProductInfo.Include(p => p)

     var ViewModel = Model.Select(x => new ProductInfoWithNoteList { MinimumProductInfoID = x.MinimumProductInfoID, ItemCode = x.ItemCode, MinimumOnHandQuantity = x.MinimumOnHandQuantity, MaximumOHandQuantity = x.MaximumOHandQuantity, MinimumOrderQuantity = x.MinimumOrderQuantity, LeadTimeInWeeks = x.LeadTimeInWeeks  });

     return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Everything else is working except now I need to include the latest note and latest comment in to my viewmodel

This is what I have now with WithMetta's help:

```
public ActionResult MinimumProductInfoList()
    {
        var productInfoViewModelCollection =
            from x in db.MinimumProductInfo
            let pnote =
                (from inner_pnote in db.ProductNotes
                 where x.MinimumProductInfoID == inner_pnote.MinimumProductInfoID
                     && inner_pnote.NoteTypeFlag == "p"
                 orderby inner_pnote.NoteDate
                 select inner_pnote).FirstOrDefault()
            let cnote =
                (from inner_cnote in db.ProductNotes
                 where x.MinimumProductInfoID == inner_cnote.MinimumProductInfoID
                      && inner_cnote.NoteTypeFlag == "c"
                 orderby inner_cnote.NoteDate
                 select inner_cnote).FirstOrDefault()
            select new ProductInfoWithNoteList
            {
                MinimumProductInfoID = x.MinimumProductInfoID,
                ItemCode = x.ItemCode,
                MinimumOnHandQuantity = x.MinimumOnHandQuantity,
                MaximumOHandQuantity = x.MaximumOHandQuantity,
                MinimumOrderQuantity = x.MinimumOrderQuantity,
                LeadTimeInWeeks = x.LeadTimeInWeeks,
                Comment = cnote.ToString(),
                PermanentNote = pnote.ToString()
            };

        return View(productInfoViewModelCollection);
    }
```

Comment: do you have a using statement for System.Data.Entity?   `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: `.Include(p => p)`??

Comment: @GertArnold Also 

    var Model = _minimumProductInfo.GetAll();

    ...

    var  Model = db.MinimumProductInfo.Include(p => p);

Comment: @GertArnold that is because I didn't finish it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this using LINQ.

```
var productInfoViewModelCollection =
    from x in db.MinimumProductInfo
    where x != null
    let pnote =
        (from inner_pnote in db.ProductNotes 
        where inner_pnote != null
            && x.MinimumProductInfoID == inner_pnote.MinimumProductInfoID
            && inner_pnote.NoteTypeFlag == "p"
        orderby inner_pnote.NoteDate descending
        select inner_pnote).FirstOrDefault()
    let cnote =
        (from inner_cnote db.ProductNotes 
        where inner_cnote != null
            && x.MinimumProductInfoID == inner_cnote.MinimumProductInfoID 
            && inner_cnote.NoteTypeFlag == "c"
        orderby inner_cnote.NoteDate descending
        select inner_cnote).FirstOrDefault()
    select new ProductInfoWithNoteList { 
        MinimumProductInfoID = x.MinimumProductInfoID, 
        ItemCode = x.ItemCode, 
        MinimumOnHandQuantity = x.MinimumOnHandQuantity, 
        MaximumOHandQuantity = x.MaximumOHandQuantity, 
        MinimumOrderQuantity = x.MinimumOrderQuantity, 
        LeadTimeInWeeks = x.LeadTimeInWeeks,
        Comment = cnote,
        PermanentNote = pnote
     };
```

Comment: It isn't allowing me to use .Max() so far the rest is working.

Comment: What type is pnote.NoteDate?

Comment: It is a DateTime

Comment: WithMetta, we are almost there.  I noticed two changes needed to your code. First, equals needs to change to == and second the first "c" needs to change to "p". 

However, I am still having a small issue.  When doing the Select new ProductInfoWithNoteList - it will not recognize pnote or cnote.  Everything up to that point works.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix the last problem?

Comment: I am marking yours as correct because you have gotten me 99% of the way there.  You are the man, I just need the last inch help.  I am not an expert yet on C#/ MVC

Comment: Can you edit your question to show me what you code looks like at this point?

Comment: Updated in Original Post

Comment: Did you add properties to the ProductInfoWithNoteList class of type ProductNotes?

Comment: Yeah I have already had them in the ViewModel.  It is the pnote and cnote that I don't have access to.

Comment: I called them PermanentNote and Comment in the ViewModel.  They existed prior to me opening up this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153411/discussion-between-withmetta-and-djblois).